# Stripe: No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload using Django

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I am getting the below error while Stripe calling the defined Web hook

> No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload

I am following this article: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/checkout#provision-and-monitor

And I have following code:

```
@csrf_exempt
def saaswebhookview(request):
    try:
        stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
        webhook_secret = 'stripe_key'
        request_data = request.POST
        if webhook_secret:
            try:
                signature = request.headers.get('stripe-signature')
                # signature = request.META['stripe-signature']
                event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(
                    payload=request.POST, sig_header=signature, secret=webhook_secret)
                data = event['data']
            except Exception as e:
                print(str(e))
                return JsonResponse({'status': 'error', 'error': str(e)})
            event_type = event['type']
        else:
            data = request_data['data']
            event_type = request_data['type']
        data_object = data['object']
        if event_type == 'checkout.session.completed':
            print(data)
        elif event_type == 'invoice.paid':
            print(data)
        elif event_type == 'invoice.payment_failed':
            print(data)
        else:
            print('Unhandled event type {}'.format(event_type))
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'success'}, safe=False)
    except Exception as e:
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'success', 'error': str(e)}, safe=False)
```

But strangely this throws me the error don't know why?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Stripe library requires the raw body of the webhook request for signature verification to work.  It looks like you're supplying [`request.POST`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST), which is an altered version of the body.

If you use [`request.body`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.body) instead it should work as expected.

Comment: and what about headers? what should i use will it be same?

Comment: i used request.body it still show the same error

Comment: Hi I also ran into this error today and Justin's advice helped me. Perhaps you, like me, at first changed data to body in the wrong place, you should do this in payload on line 12

Comment: Yep, to clarify you need to switch from `request.POST` to `request.body` inside the `stripe.Webhook.construct_event()` function.  You should *not* change the line above that sets `request_data` to `request.POST`.

Comment: Same error or a new one?  Can you update your question with the code you're currently using?  Maybe log the content of `signature` and see if it's what you expect.

Comment: Stripe doc is confusing on this. They use request.data BUT they use Flask, not Django. I guess only Django is altering the body in request.data.

Comment: If you are trying to call the webhook from the server instead of localhost then you have to set your endpoint secret to the same as this one - https://i.imgur.com/9YaYzva.png
- In the localhost endpoint secret will be the same as the webhook secret but while deploying on the server it needs to be the same as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, for to resolve my problem I decoding the body:

```
payload = request.body.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: ^ this saved my when using gcp functions - i had to do `request.data.decode('utf-8')`

Comment: This worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

**Script to verify your Stripe Webhook API with generated signature**

```
import hmac
import json
import time
from hashlib import sha256

import requests
import stripe

webhook_url = 'https://your-site/api/stripe/webhook/'
stripe_secret = 'YOUR_STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SIGN_SECRET'  # whsec_..
webhook_json_file = 'PATH_TO_JSON_FILE_WITH_WH_DATA/webhook_example.json'


def generate_stripe_signature_header(payload: dict):
    timestamp_utc = int(time.time())
    signed_payload = "%d.%s" % (timestamp_utc, payload)
    v1_sig = compute_signature(signed_payload, secret=stripe_secret)
    return f't={timestamp_utc},v1={v1_sig}'


def compute_signature(payload: dict, secret):
    """Take from stripe"""
    payload_str = json.dumps(payload)
    mac = hmac.new(
        secret.encode("utf-8"),
        msg=payload_str.encode("utf-8"),
        digestmod=sha256,
    )
    return mac.hexdigest()


with open(webhook_json_file, 'r') as f:
    payload = json.load(f)

signature = generate_stripe_signature_header(payload=payload)

headers = {
    'STRIPE-SIGNATURE': signature,  
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update(**headers)
response = session.post(webhook_url, json=payload)

print(response.content)
print(response.status_code)
response.raise_for_status()
```

**P.S.** IF you want to use it for **unit tests** / **Django Test Client**, you need to add HTTP_ prefix to the signature header

```
signature = generate_stripe_signature_header(payload=payload)
headers = {
    'HTTP_STRIPE-SIGNATURE': signature,  
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
self.client.post(webhook_url, data=payload, **headers)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was using the secret from the stripe-cli.

Instead, go the the webhook section, click your webhook and finally click `reveal secret`.  This will show the secret you want.

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by pymen worked perfectly when trying to use it for unit tests / Django Test Client. However, I kept getting the following error: "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'" and i fixed it by adding content_type='application/json' in self.client.post.

```
self.client.post(webhook_url, data=payload, content_type='application/json', **headers)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
request_body = request.body

request_data = request.data

...

event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(payload=request_body, sig_header=signature, secret=webhook_secret)
```

Comment: Maybe you should add some text before or after your code to help OP understand the problem and the solution you are offering.